# Why isnt countif function in excel not working?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to count the number of cells that contain the digits '451011' in excel. So i converted all the cells to text first and then used the formula - `=COUNTIF(A2:A28,"*451011*")`, I had about 23-24 cells containing the same, but on evaluation the formula showed the answer as 2.

[image: The Excel Screen]

As you can see in the above picture, it shows the answer as 2. Please help.

Comment: Green arrow on rows 26 and 27 are text, while the remaining are not. Try copying/pasting to notepad, then copy/paste back to excel.

Comment: Only two of those are actually numbers stored as text, se the two with the green triangles.  Just because the format is TEXT does not make them actual text.  They are still stored as numbers just shown as TEXT.

Comment: You are looking for a str in a number field. You have to convert the numbers in the A column to text then F2 on the cell to convert it.

Comment: How to convert into actual text then so that formula works, apart from the notepad way?

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(451011,A2:A28)))))`

It will work for text or values.

Comment: Hey this fixed the problem! But could you explain to me the logic behind this too, so that I can use it in other situations?

Comment: Sure!  SUMPRODUCT() will make it evaluate as an array formula. The double negative forces boolean values to be measured as numbers (so TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0). NOT() reverses TRUE and FALSE and ISERROR() will return TRUE if error and FALSE if there is no error. Finally we use FIND() to look for the exact value, which will return where in the string the value occurs or an error if it is not present.

Comment: So the formula will look at each cell to see if it contains a match. If it doesn't then it returns an error. It then changes errors to TRUE and everything else to FALSE. These values are reversed and then converted to 1 or 0, these 1's and 0's are summed and the result displayed in the cell.